# Application Registration to use End Points (Likes, Comments, Relationship) with Instagram

Tags: instagram

I want to request approval for using the End Points of LIKES, COMMENTS and Relationships in my application via instagram API.

In order to do so, i am filling the form given at following link in order to get the approval from Instagram

https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

After i fill all the information along with screen shots and click send, it doesn't give me any confirmation of receiving details of my application or send me any confirmation email.

Instead it takes me Help page at "Something's Not Working". First time, i thought i made a mistake and second time i tried after log in to my Facebook account but same thing happened again.

Please confirm if any body faced the similar situation and got a solution.

Comment: I don't remember seeing this form previously. Does anyone know if this is a recent change (after facebook acquired Instagram)? Very disappointing :( You need to fill out that form @Tiyyob has linked even to `POST` a "Like" on a media.... https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/#post_likes

Comment: @Shiva, what is the worse part that after filling this form, it doesn't give me any confirmation but takes me to Help pages and I am unsure if my request is submitted or not. Any other person faced similar situation??