# Instagram API Likes Scope

Tags: scope, instagram

Could someone shed some light on new limitation of Instagram scopes, please? I do not have a business I could request the access for as stated on https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

Comment: Another SO user has reported the same issue today here => http://stackoverflow.com/q/32466277/325521

Answer (score -1):

You can use the API using this template:

"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&response_type=code&state=DCEeFkk45A53sdfKef424&scope=follower_list");

It can help you understand the scope when you are testing mode and then you can approve your application. You can also add test user.